# How to use jquery-translate

Tags: javascript, jquery, translate

I want to use this script but I can't make it work. They have a example on the web page but it is not working.

Can someone see what is wrong with it?

[JQUERY TRANSLATE](http://jsbin.com/ozenu/1007/edit#javascript,html,live)

The reason why I need this is because I want to change language dynamically, for example when user clicks on the flag I need to translate it to that language.
And this script seems good to me as I don't have to write all the scripts again with the different translate, which will be a way too much work.

If this is not working maybe someone can provide me with some other plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't working because it depends on the now-closed Google Translate API. Google are releasing a paid-for API, but the old free API version linked to in that script has ceased to exist.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but on that page google project it says that we just use Bing app key instead of paid google api key

Comment: Bing has gone the same way. Microsoft also offer a paid-for translation API now, after removing their free service.

Comment: what's the latest on this?

Answer (score 0):

The response of the Ajax call is :

google.language.callbacks.id101('22', null, 403, 'Please use Translate v2.  See http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html', 200)

which turns back to what Jim said.

---

From the `jquery-translate` code there is :

```
if (key.length < 40) --> Google
else Microsoft
```

And I don't see the key set anywhere in your code , so this might be your problem.

---

Read the code to know how to use the library, we won't do that for you.